# Splitting occurence of string and getting specific substring javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following string
`/products/id/edit'`

i want to get the substring `products` using javascript but i am not sure how to do it? Any pointers will be great. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

String objects have a `.split()` method:

```
'/products/id/edit'.split('/')
```

Which outputs a four member array; one for each string around the slashes:

```
["", "products", "id", "edit"]
```

Does that accomplish what you're hoping for?

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. I need to figure out how to use that snippet tool, but for now I can just be more verbose.

Comment: press Ctrl+M in the answering window and use it

Comment: Keeps showing a script error for simple and perfectly valid JS